# Keys Not Defined For Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, memoization

I am trying to solve the [Maximum Length Of Pair Chain](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-length-of-pair-chain/) problem on LeetCode.
I am stuck with Memoization part for my solution.

Here, I have tried to store a 2-d tuple, which is a combination of points, as the key for the dictionary.
Everything is working fine except that I can't access the keys of the dictionary.
Even the dictionary contents are printing fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Solution:
def findLongestChain(self, pairs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    if len(pairs)==1:
        return 1
    
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(len(pairs)):
        pairs[i] =tuple(pairs[i])
    pairs = tuple(pairs)
    
    def recur_t(A,arr):
        if len(arr)==0:
            return len(A)
        if arr in d:
            print("Hello")
            return d[arr]
        else:
            maxi =len(A)
            for i in range(len(arr)):
                rem_lst = arr[:i]+arr[i+1:]
                if A==[]:
                    maxi = max (recur_t(A+[arr[i]],rem_lst),maxi)
                elif arr[i][0]<=A[-1][1]:
                    pass
                elif arr[i][0]>A[-1][1]:
                    maxi = max (recur_t(A+[arr[i]],rem_lst),maxi)
            print (arr)
            d[arr] = maxi
            return maxi
    
    
    return(recur_t([],pairs))
```

Comment: You didn't say what language this is. I've added the Python tag as a guess, please [edit] if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

#### Looks good, so far!

- For solving this problem, we would sort, check on the end of intervals, and count:

```
class Solution:
    def findLongestChain(self, pairs):
        cur_end = float('-inf')
        longest = 0
        for pair in sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1]):
            if cur_end < pair[0]:
                cur_end = pair[1]
                longest += 1
        return longest
```

- `O(N Log N)` time complexity for the sort.